# Changes on the object's scale does not affect rendered results

Tags: python, animation, bones

I wanted to apply one animation to multiple character meshes. Since several meshes have extreme scales, I calculated proper ratios for such meshes and applied before it gets rendered. However, the rendered result does not reflect such modification.

I calculated the ratio using this code:

```
char_obj = D.objects['Armature']

# If the character is too large or too small
if char_obj.dimensions[1] > 2 or char_obj.dimensions[1] < 1.5:
    random_height = 1.7 + np.random.random() * 0.2 - 0.1
    ratio = random_height / char_obj.dimensions[1]
else:
    ratio = 1
```

and applied it onto the object using this code:

```
for f in range(f_start, f_start + ani_length):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
    print('####### BEF', ratio, char_obj.name, char_obj.scale, char_obj.dimensions, '###############')
    char_obj.scale *= ratio
    bpy.context.view_layer.update() 
    print('####### AFT', ratio, char_obj.name, char_obj.scale, char_obj.dimensions, '###############')
    bpy.ops.render.render()
```

and here is the log:

```
####### BEF 0.5062162825490473 Armature <Vector (0.0100, 0.0100, 0.0100)> <Vector (1.1969, 3.3878, 0.5768)> ###############
####### AFT 0.5062162825490473 Armature <Vector (0.0051, 0.0051, 0.0051)> <Vector (0.6059, 1.7150, 0.2920)> ###############

####### BEF 0.5062162825490473 Armature <Vector (0.0100, 0.0100, 0.0100)> <Vector (1.1935, 3.3860, 0.5750)> ###############
####### AFT 0.5062162825490473 Armature <Vector (0.0051, 0.0051, 0.0051)> <Vector (0.6041, 1.7140, 0.2911)> ###############
```

I understand that the scales get initialized whenever I call frame_set due to the bone animation, but I don't know why rendered results do not reflect the changes while the object's dimension is definitely affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here.

It's not the solution for the problem but I was able to bypass it. Instead of multiplying 'ratio' to the meshe's scale, I put an additional parameter 'global_scale=ratio' when I import the animation using bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx

Hope it helps others!